# Reference Error in javascript and try catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch

A try-catch is used on a call to a backend service because there is a chance that it may return an empty response.

When the response is empty, the error is marked:

"ReferenceError: modelInfo is not defined".

The fact that the API might be down and a ReferenceError happens is to be expected.

In order to handle this error, the code is wrapped in a try-catch.

The behavior I expected with the try-catch was that it would error requesting the service info, and jump to 'catch', running that code.

The catch code doesn't run?

```
        var activeMessage = view.querySelector('#activeMessage');
        var html = '';

        try {

            //This call to the backend could throw a ReferenceError
            ApiClient.getJSON(ApiClient.getUrl("VeraModelInfo")).then(function (modelInfo) {

                html += modelInfo.Name;
                html += '<br />';
                html += modelInfo.InternalIp;
                html += '<br />';
                html += '<span id="icnConnectedContainer" style="color:rgb(82,181,75);font-size: 73%; opacity:0;">';
                html += '<i class="md-icon" style="padding-bottom: 0.5%;">';
                html += 'check_circle_outline';
                html += '</i>';
                html += '  Connected';
                html += '</span > ';

                activeMessage.style.opacity = 0;
                activeMessage.innerHTML = html;
                activeMessage.style.color = '#303030';

        }
        catch (error) { //This catch doesn't run after ReferenceError

            html += '<span style="color: red" >';
            html += '<i class="md-icon">';
            html += 'circle_remove';
            html += '</i>';
            html += '<span>';
            html += ' No Vera Home Automation Device Detected!';

            activeMessage.innerHTML = html;
            activeMessage.style.color = 'red';
            activeMessage.style.opacity = 1;
            activeMessage.style.display = 'block';

            view.querySelector('#deviceModel').style.display = "none";
        }
```

Realizing that an Error is not always an Exception...

how to throw an exception to run the catch code when there is a ReferenceError in a request.

Or recognize the ReferenceError to handle the client layout code in another function?

Comment: An error in the `.then()` callback cannot be caught by the `catch` clause; that's what the Promise mechanism is for.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up (thanks to @Pointy's suggestion) writing this and grasped the idea of Promises, which worked.

```
 var activeMessage = view.querySelector('#activeMessage');
        var html = '';

        return new Promise(() => {

            ApiClient.getJSON(ApiClient.getUrl("VeraModelInfo")).then(function (modelInfo) {


                html += modelInfo.Name;
                html += '<br />';
                html += modelInfo.InternalIp;
                html += '<br />';
                html += '<span id="icnConnectedContainer" style="color:rgb(82,181,75);font-size: 73%; opacity:0;">';
                html += '<i class="md-icon" style="padding-bottom: 0.5%;">';
                html += 'check_circle_outline';
                html += '</i>';
                html += '  Connected';
                html += '</span > ';

                activeMessage.style.opacity = 0;
                activeMessage.innerHTML     = html;
                activeMessage.style.color   = '#303030';
                activeMessage.animate({
                    transform   : ['translateX(-200px)', 'translateX(0)'],
                    opacity     : [0, 1]
                },
                    {
                        duration: 300,
                        fill    : 'forwards',
                        easing  : 'cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1)',
                        delay   : 525
                    });

                var icnConnectedContainer = view.querySelector('#icnConnectedContainer');
                icnConnectedContainer.animate({
                        opacity : [0, 1]
                    },
                    {
                        duration: 320,
                        fill    : 'forwards',
                        easing  : 'cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1)',
                        delay   : 880
                    });

                // Place the image for the users MiCasaVerde Device in an image.
                var deviceImg           = view.querySelector('#deviceModel');
                deviceImg.src           = modelInfo.ImageUrl;
                deviceImg.style.opacity = 0;
                deviceImg.style.display = 'block';
                deviceImg.animate({
                    transform   : ['scale(0.89)', 'scale(1)'],
                    opacity     : [0, 1]
                },
                    {
                        duration: 220,
                        fill    : 'forwards',
                        easing  : 'cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1)',
                        delay   : 120
                    });

                if (config.SavedDeviceProfiles) {
                    config.SavedDeviceProfiles.forEach(function (device) {
                        view.querySelector('#clientProfiles').innerHTML += (getClientHtml(device));
                    });
                }

            }, () => {

                html += '<span style="color: red" >';
                html += '<i class="md-icon">';
                html += 'error';
                html += '</i>';
                html += '<span>';
                html += ' No Vera Home Automation Device Detected!';

                activeMessage.innerHTML     = html;
                activeMessage.style.color   = 'red';
                activeMessage.style.opacity = 1;
                activeMessage.style.display = 'block';

                view.querySelector('#deviceModel').style.display = "none";
            });
```